# Python no agrega ni modifica datos.

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Amigos de Stackoverflow necesito ayuda con este codigo, pues no me esta guardando ni agregando datos a la base de datos desde el formulario html pero si desde el /admin

espero me puedan ayudar porfavor,gracias

## MODELS.PY

```
class Cuenta(models.Model):
'''
ENCABEZADO
'''
NIN_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_FECHRADICA = models.DateField()
NIN_NRORADICA = models.CharField(max_length=255)
NIN_NROFACT = models.CharField(max_length=255)
NIN_NIT_IPS = models.CharField(max_length=255)
NIN_NOM_IPS = models.CharField(max_length=255)
NIN_TIPO_AFILIADO = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_CATEGORIA_AFIL = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
TIPOS_DOCUMENTO = (('CC', 'Cedula Ciudadania'),
                   ('TI', 'Tarjeta Identidad'),
                   ('RC', 'Registro Civil'),
                   ('CE', 'Cedula Extranjeria'),
                   ('MS', 'Menor sin Identificacion'),
                   )
NIN_AFI_TID_CODIGO = models.CharField(
    max_length=2, choices=TIPOS_DOCUMENTO, default='CC', blank=True, null=True)
NIN_AFI_IDENTIFIC = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_AFI_APELLIDO1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_AFI_APELLIDO2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_AFI_NOMBRE1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_AFI_NOMBRE2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
TIPOS_SEXO = (
    ('F', 'Femenino'),
    ('M', 'Masculino'),
)
NIN_AFI_SEXO = models.CharField(
    max_length=2, choices=TIPOS_SEXO,  blank=True, null=True)
NIN_DX_CODIGO = models.ForeignKey(
    Diagnostico, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NIN_FECHA_INI_SERVICIO1 = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_FECHA_SOLICITUD_MED1 = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

TIPOS_RECOBRO = (
    ('TUTELA', 'Tutela'),
    ('TUTELAMIPRES', 'Tutela Mipres'),
    ('PRESCIPCION', 'Prescripcion'),
    ('CTC', 'Comite Tecnico Cientifico'),
)

NIN_TIPANEXO_AUTORIZACION = models.CharField(
    choices=TIPOS_RECOBRO, max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
'''
no pos
'''
NIN_ENTREGA = models.IntegerField(default='1',blank=False, null=False)
TIPOS_SERVICIO = (
    ('MD', 'Medicamento'),
    ('PD', 'Procedimiento'),
    ('AC', 'Actividad'),
    ('IN', 'Insumo'),
)
NAC_CODIGO_CUMS_CUPS = models.CharField(
    choices=TIPOS_SERVICIO, max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_COD_SERVICIO = models.CharField(
    'COD CUM/CUP', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_MAPIISS_DESCRIPCION = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_PRESENTACION = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_DOSIS_DIA = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_DIAS_TTO = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_CANT_TOTAL_TTO = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NIN_CANTIDAD_EPS = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NIN_VALOR_UNIT_EPS = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NIN_VALOR_NOPOS = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
VALOR_GLOSA_PERT =  models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
'''
Pos
'''
NAC_COD_SERV_HOMOL = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NAC_NOM_SERV_HOMOL = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_DOSIS_DIA_HOMOL = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_DIAS_TTO_HOMOL = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_CANT_TOTAL_TTO_HOM = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_VALOR_UNIT_HOM = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NAC_VALOR_TOTAL = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

NIN_VALORREC = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
VALOR_GLOSA_PERT = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
'''
ctc
'''
NIN_NUMACTA = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_FECHA_ACTA = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
'''
mipres
'''
NIN_HABILITADO = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NRO_PRESCRIPCION = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
FECHA_PRESCRIPCION1 = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
'''
tutela
'''
TIPOS_PERIODICO = (
    ('S', 'Sucesivo'),
    ('N', 'Unico'),
)
NIN_PERIODICO = models.CharField(
    choices=TIPOS_PERIODICO, default='S', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NAT_NUMERO_FALLO = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NAT_FECHA_FALLO1 = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
NAT_AUTORIDAD_JUDICIAL = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
NIN_TIPOAUT = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NAC_UBICAUT = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
'''
MISC INTERNO UT
'''
ESTADO_INTERNO = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
USUARIO_LIQUIDA = models.CharField(max_length=255)
TRAMITIMG = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
CAUSAL_ANALISTA = models.ManyToManyField(Causal)
SUBCAUSAL_ANALISTA = models.ManyToManyField(SubCausal)
FECHAR_LIQUIDA = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
OBSERVACION_CALIDAD = models.CharField(
    max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
NIN_FECHAPREST = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
PRIORIDAD = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.NIN_ID
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpRequest, Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
import datetime
from apps.liquidacion.models import Juzgado, Cuenta, Diagnostico, TrazaCuenta, Causal, SubCausal
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
 from apps.liquidacion.forms import LiquidacionForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@login_required(login_url='/')
def cuenta_view(request, id_Cuenta, NIN_NRORADICA_Cuenta):

cuenta = Cuenta.objects.get(id=id_Cuenta)
mismafac = Cuenta.objects.all().filter(NIN_NRORADICA=NIN_NRORADICA_Cuenta)
if request.method == 'GET':
  form = LiquidacionForm(instance=cuenta)
else:
  form = LiquidacionForm(request.POST, instance=cuenta)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
  return redirect('asignacion')
return render(request, 'liquidacion/liquida_form.html', {'title': 'Liquida Cuenta', 'form': form, 'mismafacs': mismafac})
```

## liquida_form.html

```
{% include "liquidacion/tablaasigna.html" %}


  <div class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="lead">Tipo Recobro</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showCTC()" href="#CTC">Comite CTC</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showPre()" href="#Prescripcion">Prescripcion</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showTut()"  href="#Tutela">Fallo Tutela</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showTutM()"  href="#TutelaMipres">Tutela Mipres</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" >Encabezado de Cuenta</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">              
                   <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4" >ID Cuenta</div> 
                         {{form.NIN_ID}}                  
                     </div>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Radicado</div> 
                        {{form.NIN_NRORADICA}}                
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Factura</div> 
                         {{form.NIN_NROFACT}}                 
                     </div>
                      <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Fecha Radicado</div> 
                         {{form.NIN_FECHRADICA}}               
                     </div>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Tipo Id</div> 
                       {{form.NIN_AFI_TID_CODIGO}}            
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Identificacion</div> 
                           {{form.NIN_AFI_IDENTIFIC}}              
                     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">1er Apellido</div> 
                      {{form.NIN_AFI_APELLIDO1}}                
                     </div>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">2do Apellido</div> 
                        {{form.NIN_AFI_APELLIDO2}}              
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">1er Nombre</div> 
                        {{form.NIN_AFI_NOMBRE1}}              
                     </div>
                      <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">2do Nombre</div> 
                          {{form.NIN_AFI_NOMBRE2}}       
                     </div>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Sexo</div> 
                      {{form.NIN_AFI_SEXO}}  
                     </div>


            </div>

          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" > Fechas y Diagnostico</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="input-group ">
    <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">NIT IPS</div> 
  {{form.NIN_NIT_IPS}} 
    <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
      <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

                  <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Nombre Prestador</div> 
                    {{form.NIN_NOM_IPS}}
                    <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
      <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </div>
                     </div>


                   <div class="input-group ">
                    <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Diagnostico</div> 
                   {{form.NIN_DX_CODIGO}}

                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="input-group ">
                      <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Fecha Prestacion Servicio</div>                     
                   {{form.NIN_FECHA_INI_SERVICIO1}} </div>
                 <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Fecha Solicitud Servicio</div> 
                    {{form.NAC_FECHA_SOLICITUD_MED1}} </div>
                 <div class="input-group ">
                  <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Tipo Evento</div> 
                    {{form.NIN_PERIODICO}} </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" > Datos Recobro</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">



                  <div id="div_ctcdata" style="display:none;" class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" > Comite Tecnico Cientifico</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                           <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Numero Acta</div>
                            {{form.NIN_NUMACTA}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="input-group ">
                            <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Fecha Acta</div>
                            {{form.NIN_FECHA_ACTA}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>


                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div id="div_presdata" style="display:none;" class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" > Prescripcion</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                          <div class="input-group ">
                            <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Fecha Prescipcion</div>
                            {{form.FECHA_PRESCRIPCION1}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Numero Prescripcion</div>
                            {{form.NRO_PRESCRIPCION}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                             <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Cod Habilitacion</div>
                            {{form.NIN_HABILITADO}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="div_tutdata" style="display:none;" class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" > Tutela</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                          <div class="input-group ">
                            <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Numero Fallo</div>
                            {{form.NAT_NUMERO_FALLO}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Fecha Fallo</div>
                            {{form.NAT_FECHA_FALLO1}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Tipo Aut Judicial</div>
                            {{form.NIN_TIPOAUT}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Numero Aut Judicial</div>
                            {{form.NAT_AUTORIDAD_JUDICIAL}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon  col-md-4 ">Ubicacion Aut Judicial</div>
                            {{form.NAC_UBICAUT}}
                            <div class="input-group-addon append col-md-1">
                              <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>






                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"> Servicio a Recobrar</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">Informacion No POS</div>
                  <div class="card-body">




              <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Entrega</div> 
                     {{form.NIN_ENTREGA}}             
                     </div>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Tipo Servicio</div> 
                        {{form.NAC_CODIGO_CUMS_CUPS}}              
                           <div class="input-group-append">
<button  type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info text-center" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" >Cargar</button>
  </div>
                       </div>
                         <div class="input-group ">
                          <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Codigo CUM/CUP</div> 
                        {{form.NIN_COD_SERVICIO}}              
                     </div>
                      <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Nombre Servicio</div> 
                          {{form.NIN_MAPIISS_DESCRIPCION}}       
                     </div>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Presentacion Servicio</div> 
                      {{form.NAC_PRESENTACION}}  
                     </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Frecuencia Uso</div> 
                      {{form.NAC_DOSIS_DIA}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Dias Autorizados</div> 
                      {{form.NAC_DIAS_TTO}}  
                     </div>
                      <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Cantidad Suministro</div> 
                      {{form.NIN_CANTIDAD_EPS}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Valor Unitario</div> 
                          <div class="input-group-addon col-md-1"> $ </div> 
                      {{form.NIN_VALOR_UNIT_EPS}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Valor Total</div> 
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-1"> $ </div> 
                      {{form.NIN_VALOR_NOPOS}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon btn-info col-md-4">VALOR RECOBRO</div> 
                          <div class="input-group-addon btn-info  col-md-1"> $ </div> 
                      {{form.NIN_VALORREC}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Glosa</div> 
                          <div class="input-group-addon col-md-1"> $ </div> 
                      {{form.VALOR_GLOSA_PERT}}
                     </div>    




                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header"> Informacion Pos</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Codigo Mappiss</div> 
                     {{form.NAC_COD_SERV_HOMOL}}             
                     </div>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Nombre Servicio</div> 
                        {{form.NAC_NOM_SERV_HOMOL}}              
                     </div>

                        <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Frecuencia Uso</div> 
                      {{form.NAC_DOSIS_DIA_HOMOL}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Dias Autorizados</div> 
                      {{form.NAC_DIAS_TTO_HOMOL}}  
                     </div>
                      <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Cantidad Suministro</div> 
                      {{form.NAC_CANT_TOTAL_TTO_HOM}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Valor Unitario</div> 
                          <div class="input-group-addon col-md-1"> $ </div> 
                      {{form.NAC_VALOR_UNIT_HOM}}  
                     </div>
                       <div class="input-group ">
                     <div class="input-group-addon col-md-4">Valor Total</div>
                          <div class="input-group-addon col-md-1"> $ </div>  
                      {{form.NAC_VALOR_TOTAL}}  
                     </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">

      <h4 class="modal-title">Carga Cum/Cup</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead class="card-header" >
          <tr>
            <th>COD</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Presentacion</th>
            <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
            <th>Fecha Fin</th>
            <th> </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                   
          <tr>
            <td> Cdigo</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Presentacion</td>
            <td>Fecha Inicio</td>
            <td>Fecha Fin</td>               
            <td> <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a></td>
          </tr> 

        </tbody>
      </table>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card">

                  <div class="card-header">Datos Cuenta</div>
                  <div class="card-body">



              <div class="col-md-12">Estado Cuenta</div> 
              <div class="input-group ">                         
                     {{form.ESTADO_INTERNO}}             
                     </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">Causal Analista</div> 
                    <div class="input-group ">

                        {{form.CAUSAL_ANALISTA}}              


                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12">SubCausal Analista</div> 
                       <div class="input-group ">

                        {{form.SUBCAUSAL_ANALISTA}}              


                     </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12">Observacion</div> 
                       <div class="input-group ">

                        {{form.OBSERVACION_CALIDAD}}              
                     </div>
                     <div class="align-center"> 
                       <div class="col-md-4">

                  <button type="submit"> GUARDAR </button>
                </div>


                    </div>





                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
  </div>







  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Donde tienes tu if form.is_valid(), utiliza un else para imprimir los errores del formulario (los campos que presentan problemas), usando lo siguiente, print(form.errors). Con ello tendrás una idea si el problema está por los datos que envías desde el formulario.

Comment: Cuál es la acción que deseas realizar, guardar un nuevo registro o editar uno existente?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver si el formulario tiene errores y los mesajes de los mismos usando este código en el template:

```
{{ if <nombre_del_formulario>.errors }}
errores:
{{ <nombre_del_formulario>.errors }}
{{ else }}
Todo chido.
{{ endif }}
```

Comment: {{ if form.errors }}
errores:
{{ form.errors }}
{{ else }}
Todo chido.
{{ endif }}

lo intente de varias formas y siempre me tira el mismo error 
 - <form>
-<LiquidacionForm>
-form
-LiquidacionForm


Could not parse the remainder: ' <LiquidacionForm>.errors' from 'if <LiquidacionForm>.errors'

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, lo que hice fue ir a mi models.py y dejar en null=true y blank=true todos los campos que no aparcen en el form, por eso no me guardaba ni modificaba los demas datos. 
gracias